# Rest API programming: Requests vs urllib2 in Python 2.7 -- the API needs authentication (Error 401)

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I am a beginner trying to learn REST API programming through Python 2.7 to get data from [Socialcast API.](https://socialcast.github.io/socialcast/) From my research it looks like requests or urllib2 would work. I need to authenticate with username and id for the API. I tried using urllib2 and it gave me error 401.

Which one should I use? My goal is to produce .csv files from the data so I can visualize it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both libraries can be used for this.  If one of them is giving you an error, post a question about that error (and include your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question will yield a bit of an opinion based response, but I would suggest using Requests. I find that when making request that require parameters using Requests is easier to manage. An example for the Socialcast using Requests would be

```
parameters={"email" : emailAddress, "passoword" : password}
r = requests.post(postUrl, parameters)
```

The post url would be the url to make the post request and emailAddress and password would be the vales you use to login in.

For the csv, take a look [here](http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-json-to-csv-using-python/) which includes a tutorial on going from json to csv.

Comment: I tried your code and got this error:

'>>> parameters = {"username" : emailAddress, "password" : password}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'emailAddress' is not defined'

Comment: @EvanMann emailAddress and password are just place holders for your email and password

Comment: It was fixed by making my username and password strings. I didn't have quotes around them. Thanks!